# How to select all divs with a specific type in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some divs in my HTML-code with the type "button" (see code below). How do I select all of these buttons and add a click-listener to them in JQuery?

```
<div class="container">
      <div lass="row">
        <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>

        <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
        <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is one of the things I have tried:

```
$('[class*="btn"]').click(function () {
  console.log("Method called!");
  $(this).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 50);

}
```

Comment: I don't think that `div`s have the `type` attribute, so maybe you should remove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$('[class*="btn"]').click(function () {
```

to

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
```

However, it's not ideal binding the same event to multiple elements - this will lead to performance issues once you get to a decent number of elements. Instead, [delegate the event](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to a parent.

```
$('.container').on('click', '.btn', function () {
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this as your JS code:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
  console.log("Method called!");
  $(this).addClass("pressed");
  var elem = $(this); // Use elem inside setTimeout function
  setTimeout(function () {
    elem.removeClass("pressed");
  }, 50);

});
```

Comment: It's always better to explain your answer rather than simply provide code. That way, the OP learns something.

Answer (score 1):

I think that type attribute can't be used with divs. Try using classes or actual buttons. Btw, if type could work with divs, jquery would look like div[type="button"]

Comment: this is not an answer post it inside comments

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can select elements using CSS attribute selector.

```js
$('div[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div lass="row">
        <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">Button 1</div>
        <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">Button 2</div>
        <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">Button 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```